# Keyboard shortcut for Terminal doesn't work since updating to 12.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, 12.10, gnome-terminal

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> assigned as my keyboard shortcut to launch a Terminal window, but it stopped working after upgrading to 12.10.

I have verified that it is still set in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings menu, and have verified that other shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open calculator) work.

I have also tried using assigning different key combinations to Terminal, to see if that helps (it doesn't), e.g. unassigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from calculator, and instead assigning it to Terminal. No dice.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Have you tried to start the app to set shortcuts via Bash? So you might see error messages if there are any?

Comment: that would be a good idea, but i haven't a clue what that keyboard shortcut menu's command is... no commands that start with keyboard-*, and nothing under gnome-* that seems to be keyboard related...

Comment: oh, solved it on my own though! your comment sparked the idea of adding a trigger for a custom command -- in this case, i explicitly called gnome-terminal; this works.

Comment: It's a bug.
See here : [BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/975416) Solution in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS was found here:
[WORKING SOLUTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403819/ctrlaltt-not-working?newreg=5d5393fb775444a88dece06ae164eb1e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it on my own, after having an idea sparked by @Mrokii.

In the `Keyboard Shortcuts` menu, I went to the  `Custom Shortcuts` section, and added a new shortcut assigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to the command `gnome-terminal`. This works!

There must be something screwy with my settings for default terminal... But I'm not going to worry about that, so long as my shortcut works.

Comment: yup, my default terminal was set to something that wasn't installed! I guess at some point I decided i liked `rxvt-unicode` better than `gnome-terminal` (though I can't recall why now), and then when I upgraded to 12.10, it uninstalled `rxvt-unicode`, while leaving my default terminal setting the same -- the shortcut wasn't working because it was calling a command that didn't exist.