# CTRL+ALT+T not working

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and till day before yesterday, the shortcut was working perfectly. But when today I pressed it, it didn't open terminal.
The terminal app still works. I am on GNOME3 3.4.2, and I updated recently using `apt-get install gnome-shell`

The Keyboard shortcuts window shows no problem - 
[image]

Pls. help, what should I do now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/975416) of Gnome Shell. The default shortcut will not work. But a new shortcut will work as usual.

Go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts. Click on  **+** to add a new shortcut,

[image]

At the place of *Name* use Gnome terminal. In place of *Command* use the following string,

```
gnome-terminal --profile=Default --geometry=95x35+250+60
```

Now assign the key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on clicking on it. Afterwards the shortcut should work.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how do I do that? I added a custom shortcut with that command, but its saying "disabled". And it didn't ask me for the accelerator for the shortcut. What do I need to do?

Comment: click on `disable`. It will say `New Accelerator`. Now type the combination on your keyboard. done

Comment: but just out of curiousity, what was not making it work?

Comment: ya, this is a bug see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/975416)

Answer (score -2):

When you're missing your Windows task, go to `Keyboard Settings` and click on `Shortcut Menu`. Then, click `Windows` and select the first options or use `Alt+Escape`.

Comment: This answer is really unclear and vague. Please explain in more specific detail your solution.